# Implementing SSO using Passive Federated Identity and login page on relying party

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wif, single-sign-on, federated-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

We have implemented SSO (Single Sign-On) for a group of websites with different domain names using passive federated identity (C#, ASP.Net MVC 3, WIF). The setup works fine as it follows the standard passive federation with login page hosted on STS.

www.brand1.com
www.brand2.com
...
www.sts.com   (login page hosted here)

Now the client wants that login pages are implemented on each relying party so that the user does not get redirected to STS. The reason is that each relying party is a known brand therefore redirecting to a different domain name (hosting STS) is not acceptable for the respective brand. Customizing login pages on STS for each brand is not acceptable either.

Is there a way to move login pages to relying parties?

Answer (score 2):

There are two routes you could go with this:

1. You can create a login page on each relying party that uses [active federation](http://www.alexthissen.nl/blogs/main/archive/2011/07/18/using-active-profile-for.aspx) to authenticate your users.  This is dependent on the STS offering a WS-Trust endpoint.
2. If you have control over the STS code, you can simply have your relying parties POST the login credentials (username/password) to the STS, and the STS site would process the authentication request as before.  This is an approach I've used successfully in the past.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Re. point 2. Do you encrypt the credentials somehow before you POST?

Comment: Encrypting the credentials is optional if you're POSTing to an HTTPS secured page.  Transport security would be used in that case.  It's really not any different than POSTing on the STS site.  The data is still being sent over the Internet.

Comment: Both methods will work for authentication, but do they satisfy the single sign-on requirement?

Comment: Since you're dealing with sites in different domains, single sign-on will be a little bit trickier.  If you use approach #2, the STS can still create a cookie on its side.  When the user authenticates on Site A and then navigates to Site B, you can have the site hop over to the STS to check for authentication.  If it fails, it can just send the user back to the login page on Site B.  Just a thought.